# Filtering European traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic

I'd like to filter incoming information, with one profile containing U.S. traffic and another E.U. traffic.

U.S. was easy enough...

```
Custom Filter
Include
Filter Field: Country
Filter Pattern: United States$
Case Sensitive: No
```

This worked great.

European traffic however has been problematic.

```
Custom Filter
Include
Filter Field: Region
Filter Pattern: Europe
Case Sensitive: No
```

The above doesn't work. I also tried "Southern Europe|Northern Europe|etc" as the filter pattern. No dice. Things are made more difficult by the fact that I can only test that worked by checking whether traffic was acquired the next day.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Continent in GA Advanced Segments. I believe using the Continent field solves your problem.

Comment: I tried that first, but it seems you have to specify something under "Continent", such as a region, as demonstrated at "0:40" here in this video: [Google Analytics - About Advanced Segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033017?rd=1). Also this thread seems to indicate "Europe" can't be filtered:  [Google Analytics Group](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-google-analytics-features-with-other-users/lJcop9keQ18). Correct me if that's not correct for some reason :-)

Comment: I checked this and it works in my Analytics. Under Continent, I specified Europe. So you would have two segments one for US with the country filter being set, the other as Europe with the continent filter being set.

Comment: +1 It appears to allow "Europe" now and corresponding results were returned (as far as I can tell). Maybe this is something they updated, and the threads on this need updating too :-)

Comment: 'Europe' is allowed in segments, but not in filters. 

So you can segment traffic after the fact based on Continent, but there's no facility in GA to filter incoming data before it gets saved into a given profile.

Filtering of incoming data is appealing, because it lets you segment with more granularity before GA starts sampling the results.